# How can I program a ESP8266 wireless adaptor in lua to connect via WPS push button method my home network

Tags: lua, hardware, esp8266, nodemcu

I've a project wherein I need a wifi device to be able to connect to a network via WPS push button. How can I enable that programmatically ? I'm using a ESP8266 wifi module running NodeMCU firmware (lua code).

Comment: I'm open to c compiler or any other firmware that will let me enable WPS functionality on ESP8266

Comment: There are several ways to do this. It depends on what you are using as your language of choice, of course nothing is exactly like what you want but you can modify the examples and make it work the way you need it. Arduino example: http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?t=1096  SDK example (C) http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=4285 I hope this helps you to get what you are looking for.